# Hide all children but first for every set of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There are multiple `wrap-content`s with multiple `wrap-inner`s inside. Now I would like to show only the first `wrap-inner` of every `wrap-content`

I've tried like so: (https://jsfiddle.net/s88jn0yo/)

```
$('.wrap-content .wrap-inner').slice(1).hide()
```

and (https://jsfiddle.net/s88jn0yo/1/)

```
$('.wrap-content'.each(function(){
    $(this).chilren('.wrap-inner').slice(1).hide()
});
```

Both aren't working. The Desired output should be:

```
111111
aaaaaaa
```

This is the HTML

```
<div class="wrap-content">
  <div class="wrap-inner">
    111111
  </div>
  <div class="wrap-inner">
    222222
  </div>
  <div class="wrap-inner">
    3333333
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap-content">
  <div class="wrap-inner">
    aaaaaaa
  </div>
  <div class="wrap-inner">
    bbbbbbb
  </div>
  <div class="wrap-inner">
    ccccccc
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)** or **[`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/)** and **[`:first-child`](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)** selectors

```js
$('.wrap-content .wrap-inner:not(:first-child)').hide();
// or $('.wrap-content .wrap-inner').not(':first-child').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap-content">
  <div class="wrap-inner">
    111111
  </div>
  <div class="wrap-inner">
    222222
  </div>
  <div class="wrap-inner">
    3333333
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap-content">
  <div class="wrap-inner">
    aaaaaaa
  </div>
  <div class="wrap-inner">
    bbbbbbb
  </div>
  <div class="wrap-inner">
    ccccccc
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use Javascript, unless required, you could use CSS:

```
.wrap-content .wrap-inner:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
}
```

See an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/q5jLb4bf/

Comment: For browsers that don't support `:not` you can do `.wrap-inner { display: none; } .wrap-inner:first-child { display: block; }`

Comment: Wow. `:not()` is supported way better than I thought. Must be getting old.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `(` in your fiddle.  Check the browsers console by pressing F12 for errors like these.

```
$('.wrap-content'.each(...)
```

Should be

```
$('.wrap-content').each(...)
```

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/s88jn0yo/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can as well use the selector `~` if you are not confident with `:not()`.

```css
.wrap-content :first-child ~ * {/* any other direct child */
  display:none;
  }
/* show them on hover ? */
.wrap-content:hover  :first-child ~ * {
  display:block;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap-content">
  <div class="wrap-inner">
    111111
  </div>
  <div class="wrap-inner">
    222222
  </div>
  <div class="wrap-inner">
    3333333
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap-content">
  <div class="wrap-inner">
    aaaaaaa
  </div>
  <div class="wrap-inner">
    bbbbbbb
  </div>
  <div class="wrap-inner">
    ccccccc
  </div>
</div>
```

use the same selectors if you want to run it via  jQuery

```
$('.wrap-content :first-child ~ *').hide();
```